# How recognize the URL enter by user in comment box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, social-networking

I am working on one social network application. In this application user can put comment like they did in Facebook.

If user enter any external link as comment, i want to highlight that link and if somebody click on it so it need to get open in other tab.

If user enter any link or URL in comment box i want handle it like Facebook did

How i can achieve this

Comment: Reg exp to match link, replace with anchor tag...

Comment: can u tell proper Reg expression

Comment: look at oembed for link handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link to find proper URL:

[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Also once you get to know it's a proper url, wrap it in an anchor tag and add `target=blank`  property to it.